# Attach resource path to model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby-on-rails-5, react-rails, webpacker

I’m currently building a Rails app that has some React components mixed in using `rails/webpacker`. They are being rendered out in views like this:

```
<%= react_component("CampaignTable", campaigns: @plan.campaigns.today, props: {tableTitle: "Upcoming"}) %>
```

The structure is that I have a `Plan` model which `has_many :campaigns`. On that `Campaign` model I have a class method to get the ones from the current day:

```
def self.today
  where('"end" >= ?', Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)
end
```

What I’d like to do is to be able to pass the `campaign_path`s into my React components as props, so that I can render out regular links to the non-React parts of the app.

Ideally my props should look like this:

```
{
  id: 18,
  budget_cents: 50000,
  created_at: "2018-03-29T00:49:58.000Z",
  // etc…
  campaign_path: "/campaigns/18"
}
```

What is the best way to approach this?